# Postgres default databases

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

I went through a re-installation of postgresql on a mac using brew and I'm not sure about some default vs user created databases.

After the installation I see 2 **users**:

- `postgres`
- `dan` (being my osx user).

These should be ok, normally they are created during installation.

Listing the **databases** I see:

- `postgres` (ok, default)
- `template1` (ok, default)
- `dan` (not sure about this)

So my questions are:

1. what happened to `template0` database? Did I deleted by accident or it's normal that postgres doesn't install it by default all the time? In case I've deleted what can I do to restore it? What's used for?
2. did postgres installed the `dan` databases for storing info on my `dan` user or did I create it in the past (and forgot)? In this case I can delete it (it has no tables). How can I be sure who created this?

Comment: What mechanism are you using to list the databases?  Perhaps that mechanism intentionally excludes template0 from the list.

Comment: You can see the true list of the databases using the query `select * from pg_database;`.

Comment: @jjanes you are right. I was using pgadmin and _template0_ was not visible. By using `\list` from the cli or `select * from pg_database;` I can see it. What's used for?